# create a new instance of bind generated obj

Tags: javascript, class, object, bind

I am creating a new class based on the `Base` class binded with external methods from the `ext` obj.

```
function Base(info) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = info.name;
    self.createNewInstance = function (data) {
        //I would like to identify the parent constructor
        // in this case, the obj containing `filter` and `find` methods
        // and use that to generate a new instance
        return new self.constructor(data);
    };
    return self;
}

var ext = {
        filter: function () {/*...*/},
        find: function () {/*...*/}
    },
    FinalClass = Base.bind(ext),
    instance1 = FinalClass({name: 'John'}),
    instance2 = instance1.createNewInstance({name: 'Mark'});

console.log(instance1); 
//--> {name: 'John', filter: [Function], find: [Function], createNewInstance: [Function]}
console.log(instance2); 
//--> {name: 'Mark'}
```

But as you can see I would like to create new instance from inside the `FinalClass` class which will be able to use the binded methods and not only the `Base` class ones.
So `instance2` would also have `filter`, `find` and `createNewInstance` methods.

I would be using different types of classes that inherit the same `Base` class, so just hardcode the bind method in there wouldn't work I'm afraid :(

Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there some misunderstanding about how javascript works. Let's analyze the code:

```
var ext = {
        filter: function () {/*...*/},
        find: function () {/*...*/}
    },
    FinalClass = Base.bind(ext),
```

So, here you have a `Base` function bound to `ext`. It means, every time you call `FinalClass`, `this` will be `ext`.

```
    instance1 = FinalClass({name: 'John'}),
```

Here you're call `FinalClass` passing an object with `name` equal to 'John'. Because in `Base` you have:

```
function Base(info) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = info.name;
    // ...
    return self;
}
```

And `this` is the instance of `ext` in `FinalClass`, it means you're *adding a new property* `name` to `ext` object. And I think you don't want that.
Then you returns `self`, it means you're returning `ext` again.

After that, you have:

```
    instance2 = instance1.createNewInstance({name: 'Mark'});
```

Let's have a look to that method:

```
self.createNewInstance = function (data) {
    return new self.constructor(data);
};
```

Because `instance1` it wasn't create using `new` operator, and it's `ext` itself, it means its constructor is `Object`, not `FinalClass` as you probably expected.

I believe you can find a better way to do what you want using prototypal inheritance and [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). However, you should be able to obtain the result you're looking for using a code similar to the follow:

```
function Base(info) {
    this.name = info.name;

    this.createNewInstance = function (data) {
        return new this.constructor(data);
    };

    return this;
}

var ext = {
        filter: function () {/*...*/},
        find: function () {/*...*/}
    };

function FinalClass(info) {
    var object = Object.create(ext);
    object.constructor = FinalClass;

    return Base.call(object, info);
}

var instance1 = FinalClass({name: 'John'}),
    instance2 = instance1.createNewInstance({name: 'Mark'});

console.log(instance1);
console.log(instance2);
// notice that `filter` and `find` won't probably be listed because are not "own properties", but the objects have them:
console.log(instance1.filter);
console.log(instance2.filter);
```

You could also write a utility method in `Base` that generalize a bit that work, so your code will looks like:

```
function Base(info) {
    this.name = info.name;

    this.createNewInstance = function (data) {
        return new this.constructor(data);
    };

    return this;
}

Base.create = function(extension) {
    return function Extendend () {
        var object = Object.create(extension);
        object.constructor = Extendend;

        return Base.apply(object, arguments);
    }
}

var ext = {
        filter: function () {/*...*/},
        find: function () {/*...*/}
    };

var FinalClass = Base.create(ext);

var instance1 = FinalClass({name: 'John'}),
    instance2 = instance1.createNewInstance({name: 'Mark'});
```

Hope it helps, if you have doubts or I misunderstood your question, just let me know!

Comment: wow thanks a lot ZER0 this was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for putting this great answer together